# How to replace content in a page, before user clicks on a link to that page?

Tags: php, html

I have a page called standard.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello [NAME]!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In another page, there is a link to standard.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/standard.html">LINK</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks on the link, I need to display standard.html with "John" instead of [NAME]. Maybe using str_replace?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There are many approaches - redirects, AJAX, etc. - it just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Your question title states something different that the question content. You are unable to change content before someone clicks on it. However, you are able to change content before it is displayed. There is a difference. Sorry for being a nit pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to change the link `/standard.html` to another page, such as `/standard.php` or even `general.php?page=standard`. And then in the PHP file use `file_get_contents()` and `str_replace` to output the stuff you want.

If you don't want to change the link, you can also use apache rewrite rules, to let the browser point to a file, but have it actually give another file. So you can point to `/standard.html`, but the rewrite rules makes you serve `/general.php`. And `/general.php` can use `file_get_contents()` to open `/standard.html` and use `str_replace` to replace the name.

Comment: Using first option, is it possible to sent some data, like $name to standard.php without using GET?

Comment: @Danilo You can use POST, COOKIE, SESSION, read from another file, whatever.

Comment: @Danilo Let me ask you: How do you know what his name is anyway ?

Comment: I have two files: user.html.php that shows the link and user.src.php that gets data of the user by functions and stores it in variables like $name. I need to display $name instead of [NAME] in standard.php, but without using GET (can't let the user changes the URL).

Comment: @Danilo, then in user.html.php store the user data such as `$name` into the `$_SESSION['name']` variable. (Don't forget to do `session_start();` first.) Now have user.html.php link to `/general.php` in stead of `/standard.html`. And create a file called `general.php` and put this in it: `<?php session_start(); echo str_replace('[name]', $_SESSION['name'], file_get_contents('standard.html')); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You could send and retrieve a GET parameter:

standard.html becomes standard.php

```
<p><?php echo $_GET['name']; ?></p>
```

The link to standard.php would in your case be

```
<a href=/standard.php?name=John>LINK</a>
```

Comment: I can't use GET because information can't be changed in the URL.

Comment: So you're not controlling the site linking to standard.html? In that case, you can't really make it change dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but change `standard.html` to `standard.php`
and then try

`<a href="/standard.php?name=John">LINK</a>` in the page where the link is located and

`<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>` on the page that recieves.